# Returning multiple objects from an interating function

Tags: r, function, iteration, output

I tried to save the outcome of an iterating function over two years in different objects.

My loop looks like this:

```
years <- c(2018, 2019)

for (i in seq_along(years)) {

if (i == 1) {
input_file <- "excelsheet 2019.xlsx"
} else {
input_file <- paste0("excelsheet ", years[i-1], ".xlsx")
}

fct1 <- read_excel(input_file)

fct2 <- read_cols(input_file)

fct3 <- read_data(input_file)

output[i] <- tidy(fct3)

}
```

I want the output for each iteration to be saved in the global environment. Any help is really appreciated, thanks.

Comment: It is not clear what you want. Your loop has *two* iterations, so both input files are processed and you cannot obtain "diffferent ouputs". Have you thought about stroing the result in a `list`? Lists can combine arbitrary objects.

Comment: `output` is not initiated anywhere. And I do not see the variable `st` anywhere too. You are defining three `fct` variables, but then they do not seem to relate with the output.

Comment: as not clear the task for me too, maybe `assign("value", value, envir = .GlobalEnv)`

Comment: @KestutisVinciunas This is basically *never* an appropriate solution for this kind of issue, and is likely to lead OP down the road of poorly maintainable code.

Comment: To pick up on @cdalitz 's suggestion, I would use `lapply()` or `purrr::map()` or its variants instead of a for loop here, and save your steps as shown here into a custom function that would be iterated over.

Comment: "I want the output for each iteration to be saved in the global environment."  R has different scoping rules than C. In particular, an opening brace does not start a new scope that is cleaned up at the closing brace. Variables declared inside the loop will be reachable from outside. Try it out: `if (TRUE) { a <- 1}; print(a)`